# how to fetch particular attribute value from xml

Tags: c#, xml

```
  <test-case 
       name="Fiserv.QA.NewUI.Settings.ChangeAddressTelephoneNumber.ChangeAddress.Workflow.ChangeAddressTelephoneNumberTests.ChangeAddressFuncationality" 
       executed="True" 
       result="Success" 
       success="True" 
       time="102.315" 
       asserts="14">
```

I tried this

```
 dr[0] = node.SelectSingleNode("properties/property").Attributes["value"].Value;
 dr[1] = node.Attributes["name"].Value;
 dr[2] = node.Attributes["success"].Value;
```

But its not able to find the success attribute value and meanwhile its fetching name correctly. I would like to fetch the success value. Can anyone please tell me?

Answer (score 1):

```
xml.Descendants("test-case").Select(e => e.Attribute("success").Value).ToList()
```

Try something like the above